# Control Raspberry Pi or Arduino Remotely using a remote server (IoT)

Tags: meteor, server, digital-ocean, iot, cylon.js

I basically want to be able to access a webpage/web app from any computer to control a servo or read temperatures from temperature sensors connected to an Arduino or Raspberry Pi (doesn't matter to me I have both) that is remotely connected to the internet.

I would probably use Meteor.js for the webapp because I am familiar with it and can use Mongo to store data like temperature readings from the Arduino.
I came across Cylon.js, but there is no documentation on hosting it on a remote server.

I don't want to use the Raspberry Pi or my own computer as a server, I want something more reliable like Digital Ocean or something.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal use-case of remote monitoring. This is how you can implement this in a reliable way:

- Send temperature reading from the Pi to cloud (Azure IoT Hub)
- Build your website and connect to IoT Hub from your website. Once done, host this website online (Azure Web Apps)

You're done!

Resources: Connecting to IoT Hub: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/iot/get-started/ , 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks

Deploying website: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/

Azure free trial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/

Note that IoT Hub can store data for a maximum of 7 days (as of today). If you wish to use persistent storage, use either your own service/event processor or Stream Analytics (managed service) to store the data in persistent storage. 
IoT Hub can also help in cloud-to-device messaging if you wish to do so.

Comment: That looks like a great resource, thanks!  I can find multiple tutorials on reading data from sensors but what about actually controlling something remotely?  Like ideally I click an on/off button on a website and it remotely turns a motor on/off.

Comment: This is a use-case of cloud-to-device messaging. Have a look at cloud-to-device samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks#samples

Comment: @PostitAbroad A reminder - please mark one of the answers as accepted answer if it solves your issue and you're happy with it.

Comment: This answer has pointed me the right direction.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in trying the Watson IoT Platform,   [recipes](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/) are available to help you get started and there are also sample code available in [GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/).

Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/02/tutorial-using-a-raspberry-pi-python-iot-twilio-bluemix/) that includes pressing a HTML button in the Python Flask app in Bluemix to either turn on or off an LED on Raspberry Pi.